# How do you mute another player?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In the current Beta I cannot seem to find a way to mute annoying people that are using the in game voice communication.

In the previous versions of counter-strike (source) you could bring up a player list by hitting escape and selecting that player and hitting the Mute player button. However, I cannot find this button currently.

Is there a menu that I haven't found yet or does it just not exist?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They must have changed it again, here's the new answer.

1. Bring up scoreboard
2. Press the right mouse button to enable the mouse cursor
3. Left click the player you wish to mute in the scoreboard
4. Select "Block Communication"

Answer (score 16):

Hold down TAB to bring up the player list. Then use your arrow keys to go up or down the list to the player you want to mute. Hit the ENTER key to bring up a dialog for the selected player. You can mute him, commend him, or report him.

As far as telling which player is muted, their player icon on the list should have a little muted symbol. As seen in this picture.
 [image]

Comment: One last thing from a recent match. As of this moment there is a glitch where it appears you cannot mute your team. But if you look very closely, the icon still appears but is behind their user picture instead. Why it does this I have no idea, but I thought it was useful to comment on it.

Comment: Well that's a silly way of setting it up initially.

Comment: +1 for you. I REALLY wish I had known this last night. Had one of the stupidest, most talkative guys I've ever met in my life on the server...

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would like to add this is the most convoluted process I've ever seen to do such a simple thing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though they have changed the way you mute players. For me, hitting DELETE did not do it, but if I hit ENTER after using TAB and the arrow keys, then I got a small dialog for that player. In it there was a check-box for "Disable Communication from This Player" which muted them perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use console to bind specific button to mute all users.

For example, if I want to use F11 and F12 for mute then it will be
(inside the console simply type line below and press enter for the each line)

bind "F11" "voice_enable 0"
bind "F12" "voice_enable 1"

Now you can use F11 to mute everyone and F12 to remove mute.

Comment: This command only disables voice chat, text chat is still enabled. He also asked how to mute individual players.